# Yii2 restricting access to RBAC Module itself

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How I can restrict access to RBAC Module itself?

I'm using `yii\rbac\DbManager` and I have created a module(Authorization) in backend for permission assignment,create auth items, now I want to make sure only admin can access this module!

In controller I have used something this and it's working fine.

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

class MyController extends Controller
{
 public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete'], //only be applied to
                'rules' => [
                    [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update','delete'],
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                 ],
            ],
  .........
```

I have put this in Authorization.php init function but nothing happen, all auth controllers are accessable.

```
public function init()
    {
        if(\Yii::$app->user->can('admin'))
            parent::init();

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }
```

### Update

backend/config/main.php

```
'modules' => [
        'authorization' => [
            'class' => 'backend\modules\authorization\Authorization',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: you should assign the roles based resctinction in every controller you need ..

Comment: @scaisEdge , Bizley solution is perfect. I have tried this also: `'modules' => [
        'authorization' => [
            'class' => 'backend\modules\authorization\Authorization',
            'as access'=>[
                'class'=>'yii\filters\AccessControl'
             ],
        ],
    ],  `

Comment: Thanks  .. but i prefer set the roles pemission in controller ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module class you can add this method

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!\Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) {
        throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to access this page.');
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Class 'backend\modules\authorization\ForbiddenHttpException' not found

Comment: Fix: `yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException`

Comment: Obviously I have not added fully qualified name. You would get this in like 10 seconds with any good IDE. Just in case `Yii::$app` should be `\Yii::$app` if not added in `use` statement.